# makefile goal that only needs to be executed once

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to produce `a.txt` from `a.tar.gz` in the directory. I tried writing the following goal in Makefile:

```
a.txt: a.tar.gz
  tar xvf a.tar.gz
```

This works, but after running it once `a.tar.gz` is uncompressed and no longer exists. And subsequent `make` fails. How can I write a goal that checks if `a.txt` does not exist, and if so run `tar`, but otherwise don't do anything?

Comment: `tar` doesn't normally delete the tarfile, nor even create a decompressed version. Is there no other option or command you are executing?

Comment: Also, without the `z` flag, `tar` cannot correctly unzip the file (unless of course the file name extension is wrong, and it's not really a `.gz` file at all).

Comment: @tripleee: gnu tar can autodetect compression formats so the z (and other) flags are normally unnecessary.

Comment: @rici oh, I didn't know, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wildcard` will only expand to something if it can find at least one file:

```
a.txt: $(wildcard a.tar.gz)
    tar xvmf $<
```

Adding the `m` flag will avoid unnecessary remakes.

The rule will fail if neither file exists however, but without knowing what exactly you're trying to do it's hard to provide a comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 0):

The 'test' or ' [ ' and ' ] ' can do this.

```
a.txt:
   if [ -e a.tar.gz ]; then \
   tar xvf a.tar.gz \
   fi
```

Comment: This removes the dependency from Make's view, which seems like potentially a bad thing.

Comment: He wrote "checks if a.txt does not exist, and if so run tar, but otherwise don't do anything?" so it's not a *dependency* per se.